# MongoDB aggregation with Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need your help for using MongoDB aggregation framework with java driver.
I don't understand how to write my request, even with [this documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/aggregation/).

I want to get the 200 oldest views from all items in my collection. Here is my mongo query (which works like I want in console mode):

```
db.myCollection.aggregate(
    {$unwind : "$views"},
    {$match : {"views.isActive" : true}},
    {$sort : {"views.date" : 1}},
    {$limit : 200},
    {$project : {"_id" : 0, "url" : "$views.url", "date" : "$views.date"}}
)
```

Items in this collection have one or many views.
My question is not about the request result, I want to know the java syntaxe.

Comment: Show us what you have tried for now event if it isn't working. Do not expect SO to write your code for you

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Finally found the solution, I get the same result than with the original request.

#### Mongo Driver 3 :

[Aggregate doc](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/async/client/MongoCollection.html#aggregate-java.util.List-)

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("myCollection");

AggregateIterable<Document> output = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        new Document("$unwind", "$views"),
        new Document("$match", new Document("views.isActive", true)),
        new Document("$sort", new Document("views.date", 1)),
        new Document("$limit", 200),
        new Document("$project", new Document("_id", 0)
                    .append("url", "$views.url")
                    .append("date", "$views.date"))
        ));

// Print for demo
for (Document dbObject : output)
{
    System.out.println(dbObject);
}
```

You can make it more readable with static import :
`import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.*;`.
See [koulini answer for complet example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49924761/2666094).

#### Mongo Driver 2 :

[Aggregate doc](https://api.mongodb.com/java/2.13/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#aggregate-java.util.List-)

```
Iterable<DBObject> output = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        (DBObject) new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$views"),
        (DBObject) new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("views.isActive", true)),
        (DBObject) new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("views.date", 1)),
        (DBObject) new BasicDBObject("$limit", 200),
        (DBObject) new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("_id", 0)
                    .append("url", "$views.url")
                    .append("date", "$views.date"))
        )).results();
    
// Print for demo
for (DBObject dbObject : output)
{
    System.out.println(dbObject);
}
```

---

*Query conversion logic :*
[image: Query conversion logic]
Thank to [this link](http://pingax.com/trick-convert-mongo-shell-query-equivalent-java-objects/)

Comment: Which Document you use exactly, I use Mongo driver 3.4, and in this class : com.mongodb.DBCollection, there is only aggregate function which use  DBObject not Document ? => public AggregationOutput aggregate(final List<? extends DBObject> pipeline)

Comment: It's a `MongoCollection` from `com.mongodb.async.client`. Where the method is : `aggregate(List<? extends Bson> pipeline)`. And `Document` implements `Bson`, so everything is fine.

Comment: You saved my day.

Answer (score 7):

It is worth pointing out, that you can greatly improve the code shown by the answers here, by using the Java Aggregation methods for MongoDB.

Let's take as a code example, the OP's answer to his own question.

```
AggregateIterable<Document> output = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
        new Document("$unwind", "$views"),
        new Document("$match", new Document("views.isActive", true)),
        new Document("$sort", new Document("views.date", 1)),
        new Document("$limit", 200),
        new Document("$project", new Document("_id", 0)
                    .append("url", "$views.url")
                    .append("date", "$views.date"))
));
```

We can rewrite the above code as follows;

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.*;

AggregateIterable output = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
                unwind("$views"),
                match(new Document("views.isActive",true)),
                sort(new Document("views.date",1)),
                limit(200),
                project(new Document("_id",0)
                        .append("url","$views.url")
                        .append("date","$views.date"))
));
```

Obviously, you will need the corresponding static import but beyond that, the code in the second example is **cleaner**, **safer** (as you don't have to type the operators yourself every time), more **readable** and more **beautiful** IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Using previous example as a guide, here's how to do it using mongo driver 3 and up:

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("myCollection");
AggregateIterable<Document> output = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
    new Document("$unwind", "$views"),
    new Document("$match", new Document("views.isActive", true))
));

for (Document doc : output) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to count employee by departmentId..
Details at: [Aggregation using Java API](http://ashutosh-srivastav-mongodb.blogspot.in/2017/09/mongodb-aggregation-using-java-api.html)

```
        Map<Long, Integer> empCountMap = new HashMap<>();

        AggregateIterable<Document> iterable = getMongoCollection().aggregate(Arrays.asList(
                new Document("$match",
                        new Document("active", Boolean.TRUE)
                                .append("region", "India")),
                new Document("$group",
                        new Document("_id", "$" + "deptId").append("count", new Document("$sum", 1)))));

        iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
            @Override
            public void apply(final Document document) {
                empCountMap.put((Long) document.get("_id"), (Integer) document.get("count"));
            }
        });
```