# Get Average from Mongo Collection using Aggrerate

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to learn how to use the Mongo in Java and have been able to make some simple queries but I have been having trouble with the aggregate operator.

The document structure is a simple one, as the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57dbe94f0507a4d8710ac5b2"),
    "name" : "Name1",
    "age" : 23
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57dbe9750507a4d8710ac5b3"),
    "name" : "Name2",
    "age" : "String for examble"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57dbee630507a4d8710ac5b5"),
    "name" : "Name3",
    "age" : 24
}
```

All I want to do is get the average of the `ages` in the collection ( name example ).

Simply using mongo I can get the desirable result with the following consult:

```
db.example.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null, 
            averageAge: { $avg: "$age" }
        }
    }
]);
```

I have tried the following:

```
BasicDBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", "null");
BasicDBObject media = new BasicDBObject("$avg", "$age");
groupFields.put("mediaIdade", media);
BasicDBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields );
AggregateIterable<org.bson.Document> agregate = db.getCollection("exemplo").aggregate(Arrays.asList (group));
```

Which is almost a direct translation but got a `"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bson.codecs.BsonTypeClassMap.keys()Ljava/util/Set;"` , unsurprisingly.

But I cannot translate that to Java. I have checked and found  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643109/mongodb-aggregation-with-java-driver)  but could not understand it due to the use of opperators such as `$unwind`. So I'm trying to make query as simple as possible to better understand how the Java framework for aggregation works.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
MongoCollection<Document> dbCollection = db.getCollection("example", Document.class);
AggregateIterable<org.bson.Document> aggregate = dbCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(Aggregates.group("_id", new BsonField("averageAge", new BsonDocument("$avg", new BsonString("$age"))))));
Document result = aggregate.first();
double age = result.getDouble("averageAge");
```

Input:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58136d6ed96cc299c224d529"), "name" : "Name1", "age" : 23 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58136d6ed96cc299c224d52a"), "name" : "Name2", "age" : 26 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58136d6ed96cc299c224d52b"), "name" : "Name3", "age" : 24 }
```

Output:

```
24.333333333333332
```

Comment: I get the same exception than the one in the original post.

Comment: Added the input and output to the post.

Comment: Hey! I made it work. It was all a issue with conflicting Document type, as they were being imported from two different classes. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I  noticed a small  typo in your  code:

```
db.getCollection("exemplo").aggregate(Arrays.asList (group));
```

Should be `example` instead of `examplo`

Also  the  easiest way to translate working mongo expression is  using  `Document.parse` method.

In your case it could  be:

```
db.getCollection("exemplo").aggregate(Arrays.asList(
   Document.parse("{ $group: { _id: null, averageAge: { $avg: '$age' } } }")
));
```

Your  impl also almost correct, two minor  issues:

- replace  `"null"` string with just `null` value
- Use `"averageAge"` instead  of  `"mediaIdade"`

  ```
  BasicDBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id", null);
  BasicDBObject media = new BasicDBObject("$avg", "$age");
  groupFields.put("averageAge", media);
  BasicDBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields );
  AggregateIterable<org.bson.Document> agregate = db.getCollection("exemple").aggregate(Arrays.asList (group));
  ```

To get result:

```
   agregate.first().getDouble("averageAge");
```

Comment: The aggregate function seems to run but when i try to get the result, it throws the same exception described on the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", 0);
groupFields.put("average", new BasicDBObject( "$avg", "$age"));
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);
AggregationOutput output = db.getCollection("exemplo").aggregate(group);
Iterable<DBObject> list = output.results();
```

If required add a filter to the query you can add a match parameter:

```
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject();
match.put("age", new BasicDBObject("$gte", 25));
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", 0);
groupFields.put("average", new BasicDBObject( "$avg", "$age"));
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);
AggregationOutput output = db.getCollection("exemplo").aggregate(match, group);
Iterable<DBObject> list = output.results();
```