# How can we count the number of items in arraylist from different documents in mongodb java?

Tags: java, sql, mongodb, search, count

Assuming I have these documents:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", "description" : "product 1", colors: [ "blue", "black", "red" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "ABC2", "description" : "product 2", colors: [ "blue", "purple" ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "XYZ1", "description" : "product 3", colors: [ "red", "yellow"] }
```

The result I would like is

```
blue : 2 
red : 2
black : 1
purple : 1
yellow : 1
```

Is this possible to perform using the mongodb or do I need to manually implemented after getting colors array in Java? Hints or any help would be of very useful.

This is how I get the database and the collections

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoClient.getDatabase("tweets")
            .getCollection("tweet");
```

Comment: For versions <= 3.2 you can use `db.collection.aggregate({$unwind:"$colors"},{$group: { _id:"$colors",count:{$sum:1} }})
`

Comment: I am using version 3.2, but I am new to mongodb, can you give me a more clearer explanation @Veeram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below aggregation.

```
db.collection.aggregate({$unwind:"$colors"},{$group: { _id:"$colors",count:{$sum:1} }})
```

The query will `$unwind` the array. From the docs

> Deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a
>   document for each element.

Response after `$unwind` stage.

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", "description" : "product 1", "colors" : "blue" }
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", "description" : "product 1", "colors" : "black" }
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC1", "description" : "product 1", "colors" : "red" }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "ABC2", "description" : "product 2", "colors" : "blue" }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "ABC2", "description" : "product 2", "colors" : "purple" }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "XYZ1", "description" : "product 3", "colors" : "red" }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "XYZ1", "description" : "product 3", "colors" : "yellow" }
```

Next step is to `$group` the data on `color` while using `$sum` to count the colors

Final Output

```
{ "_id" : "yellow", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "blue", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "black", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "red", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "purple", "count" : 1 }
```

Java Update:

3.x Version

```
collection.aggregate( Arrays.asList(Aggregates.unwind("$colors"), Aggregates.group("$colors", Accumulators.sum("count", 1))));
```

2.x Version

```
collection.aggregate( Arrays.asList(new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$colors"), new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject("_id","$colors").append("count",new BasicDBObject("$sum", 1)))));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. I actually do understand how aggregate works in mongodb. I am having trouble fitting in with the java syntax.

Comment: Np. What is the trouble ? Can you show your java code ?

Comment: I am not sure where I can put $unwind and $unwind. 
I am looking into the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643109/mongodb-aggregation-with-java-driver but still have no clue

Comment: It forces me to switch to this and caused an error
table.aggregate((List<? extends DBObject>) Arrays.asList(Aggregates.unwind("$colors"), Aggregates.group("$colors", Accumulators.sum("colors", 1))));

Comment: What is your mongo java driver version ? Can you please add the rest of the code to the post where you get collection and connection ?

Comment: it was 2.10 now i switched it to 3.2

Comment: Added both the 2.x and 3.x variant.

Comment: It works fine should i use normal cursor to show the results?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135307/discussion-between-veeram-and-chit-khine).

Comment: The `aggregate` returns `AggregateIterable` which is just a wrapper over cursor. You can use that to map the data.