# joining multiple records from the subarray

Tags: java, mongodb

I've an employee record with leads array containing id's only, essentially other employees that he leads.

I want to output the result joining each lead with it's name from the employee collection

**employee** collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0ba"),
    "name" : "John"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0bb"),
    "name" : "Jane"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0b4"),
    "name" : "Richard"
}
```

**employee_leads** collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d55ac30e533bc76e4581923"),
    "employee_id" : ObjectId("5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0c5"),
    "leads" : [ 
        ObjectId("5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0ba"), 
        ObjectId("5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0bb")
    ]
}
```

Expected output

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0c3"),
    "leads" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0ba"),
            "name" : "John"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d4dc8635dd32dbcba4ae0bb"),
            "name" : "Jane"
        }
    ]
}
```

Attempt:

```
Document match = new Document("$match", new BasicDBObject("_id", new ObjectId("5d55ac30e533bc76e4581923")));

Document lookup = new Document("$lookup", new BasicDBObject("from", "employee"))
        .append("localField", "leads")
        .append("foreignField", "_id")
        .append("as", "leads");

// Document unwind = new Document("$unwind", "$leads");

Document project = new Document("$project", new BasicDBObject("name", "$lead.name"));

Document document = database.getCollection("employee_lead")
        .aggregate(Arrays.asList(match, lookup, unwind, project))
        .first();

// TODO: iterate through the lead array and display it
```

The question, is there a single join statement or do I've to do multiple calls to database (naive way)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to make multiple calls to database, [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) will do exactly what you want in the Aggregation framework.

Try the following query:

```
db.getCollection("employee_leads").aggregate([
{
        $match : {
            "_id" : new ObjectId("5d55ac30e533bc76e4581923") // This is in case you want to filter anything. 
        }
},
{
        $lookup : {
            "from": "employee",
            "localField": "leads",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "leads"
        }
}])
```

Java equivalent code for above query:

**Example 1**

```
List<Bson> aggregates = Arrays.asList(
                Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("_id", new ObjectId("5d55ac30e533bc76e4581923"))),
                Aggregates.lookup("employee", "leads", "_id", "leads"));
        AggregateIterable<Document> iterable = this.collection.aggregate(aggregates);
```

**Example 2**

```
List<Document> aggregates = Arrays.asList(
        new Document("$match", new Document("_id", new ObjectId("5d55ac30e533bc76e4581923"))),
        new Document("$lookup", new Document("from", "employee")
        .append("localField", "leads")
        .append("foreignField", "_id")
        .append("as", "leads")));

AggregateIterable<Document> iterable = collection.aggregate(aggregates);

for (Document row : iterable) {
    System.out.println(row.toJson());
}
```

Comment: Simple and sweet!!

Comment: @MrS.Sharma I'll try translating this code into Java, based on your previous answer, the $unwind was a new concept to me and that concerns me a bit while attempting it in java

Comment: would highly appreciate if you can support this answer with some java code.

Comment: @AppDeveloper Sure.

Comment: @AppDeveloper Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643109/mongodb-aggregation-with-java-driver