# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.client.internal.AggregateIterableImpl cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongodb-query

I have got below document . I need to match with the requestParam System  Bob with the below collection and need to get the result value if requestParam matches with the Email Systems.Bob.System.

Here RequestParam is system

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f0890e870e631865877e"), 
    "user" : "testuser", 
    "Email" : "testuser@sample.com", 
    "Batch Systems" : [
        "STAR", 
        "STORY", 
        "ITEMS",    
    ], 
    "Email Systems" : [
        {
            "Bob" : {
                "System" : "Bob", 
                **"result"** : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "Wild" : {
                "System" : "Wild", 
                "result" : true
            }
        },
        {
            "CRaft" : {
                "System" : "Craft", 
                "result" : false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried with the below syntax , getting the java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mongodb.client.internal.AggregateIterableImpl cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList . Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the below code and help me with the synatx .

```
MongoDatabase database = this.mongoClient.getDatabase(this.database);
    MongoCollection<Document> user = database.getCollection(COLLECTION);
    Document userQuery = new Document();
    String searchString = new String(system);
    AggregateIterable<Document> user1 =users.aggregate((List<? extends Bson>) new Document("$project",
                new Document("Email Systems",
                        new Document("$match",
                                new Document("Email  Systems.BobSystem",searchString)))));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object returned by users.aggregate() is an AggregateIterable. ArrayList does not implement this interface so your cast fails. Try to cast and work with it as an AggregateIterable or AggregateIterableImpl.

Comment: I have tried AggregateIterable also it is giving java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bson.Document cannot be cast to java.util.List    AggregateIterable<Document> user1 =users.aggregate((List<? extends Bson>) new Document("$project",
                new Document("Claim Systems",
                        new Document("$match",
                                new Document("Claim Systems.AtlasSystem",searchString)))));

Comment: Is there anything wrong with Java synatx , anyother way to get the result value

Comment: You added an other false cast, try to avoid any, e.g.: AggregateIterable doc = users.aggregate(Collections.singletonList(...));

Comment: I tried below syntax AggregateIterable<Document> user1 =users.aggregate((List<? extends Bson>) new Document("$project",
                new Document("Claim Systems",
                        new Document("$match",
                                new Document("Claim Systems.AtlasSystem",searchString))))); .It is aslo giving same exception

Answer (score 1):

`users.aggregate()` return an `AggregateIterable` and not an `ArrayList` hence the error.
You can create an `Iterator` from `AggregateIterable` and then add documents to an `ArrayList`.

```
MongoDatabase database = this.mongoClient.getDatabase(this.database);
MongoCollection<Document> user = database.getCollection(COLLECTION);
Document userQuery = new Document();
String searchString = new String(system);
AggregateIterable aggregateIterable = users.aggregate(Collections.singletonList(new Document("$project", new Document("Email Systems", new Document("$match", new Document("Email Systems.Bob.System", searchString))))));
// Create an iterator from the iterable
Iterator iterator = aggregateIterable.iterator();
ArrayList<Document> documents = new ArrayList();
// Then iterate over the iterator
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    documents.add((Document) iterator.next());
}
```

See [MongoDB aggregation with Java driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643109/mongodb-aggregation-with-java-driver) for detailled answer per driver version

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Issam ,I have tried as suggested but getting below exception .'                                      
 Unrecognized expression '$match

Comment: Welcome. I see that you have edited your question after i posted my answer. Is it working for you now?

Comment: Still  facing an issue.Getting an exception  casting exception java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bson.Document cannot be cast to java.util.List .One more Query I have ,Do we need to add Documents if we want to get the 'N' of Systems value

Comment: You are trying to cast a Document to List with this (List<? extends Bson>) hence the error. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643109/mongodb-aggregation-with-java-driver it might help.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for sharing the link .It helped a lot .And I changed the synatx as below           AggregateIterable<Document> aggregateIterable = users.aggregate(Arrays.asList(new Document("$project", new Document("Claim Systems", new Document("$match", new Document("Claim Systems.Atlas", searchString))))));
        Iterator iterator = aggregateIterable.iterator();
        ArrayList<Document> documents = new ArrayList();
// Then iterate over the iterator
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            documents.add((Document) iterator.next());
        }/

Comment: Glad it helped. Plz accept the answer it could help others

Comment: It is giving the exception Command failed with error 168 (InvalidPipelineOperator): 'Unrecognized expression '$match'

Comment: Try @gibbs suggestion on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63723769/command-failed-with-error-168-invalidpipelineoperator-unrecognized-expressi