# "Command failed with error 168 (InvalidPipelineOperator): 'Unrecognized expression '$match'

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Getting exception

> Command failed with error 168 (InvalidPipelineOperator): 'Unrecognized expression '$match

What is wrong with my syntax?

```
 String searchString = new String(sourceSystem);
    AggregateIterable<Document> aggregateIterable = users.aggregate(Arrays.asList(new Document("$project", new Document("Email Systems", new Document("$match", new Document("Email Systems.Bob", searchString))))));
    Iterator iterator = aggregateIterable.iterator();
    ArrayList<Document> documents = new ArrayList();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        documents.add((Document) iterator.next());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you have `match` inside `project`

It should be `array list`  of stages. First element should be either `match` or `project`.

```
Document matchDoc = new Document(\*matching condition*/);

Document projectDoc = new Document(/*project doc*/);
```

Pass these two array list.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion .Updated as suggested .But it is not giving proper results Document matchDoc = new Document("Email Systems.Bob",searchString);
 Document projectDoc = new Document("$Email Systems","Email Systems");
AggregateIterable<Document> aggregateIterable = users.aggregate(Arrays.asList( new Document("$elemmatch", matchDoc))); and Iterator logic . It should give only matching results and need to compare with the Request Param System but it is giving both results[Document{{Bob=Document{{System=Bob,result=true}}}},Document{{Wild=Document{{System=Wild, result=true}}}}]

Comment: It is not giving matching values rather it is printing all values like below results[Document{{Bob=Document{{System=Bob,result=true}}}},Document{{Wild=Document{{System=Wild, result=true}}}}] . I need to compare with the input request param .If {System = bob , Need to take the result value of Bob system or if it is wild I should take the result of wild .Can you please help me with java synatx

Comment: I feel that is a separate question. Please post a ques with your sample data and tried portion. Anyone could help from this forum.